# PYTHON - Converting tuple to string

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples, typeerror

I have this `[(5,)]`, which I believe is a tuple within a list and I would like to just get the value 5.

I have tried `''.join(variable)` but that raised this error: `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, tuple found`.

I don't think an indexed approach would work either as the value `5` could be any positive integer (i.e. sometimes you would need to return multiple digits).

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `variable[0][0]` will return the number, str(variable[0][0])` will turn it into a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tuple_list = [(5,)]

for item in tuple_list:
    print(item[0]) # --> 5
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `var[0][0]` to get your number, in case that `var` is your variable.